how can i get camera access in ios12 application embedded h5
i can sure the app already hava the camera access, but in the embedded html, i still cannot open the camera. And this HTML page is work at Safari, but cant work on app when the page is embedded in app.
there is the error message: DOMException: undefine is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')
#pragma mark UIImagePickerController delegate
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
requestMediaCapturePermissionForOrigin:(WKSecurityOrigin *)origin
initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame type:(WKMediaCaptureType)type
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKPermissionDecision decision))decisionHandler
API_AVAILABLE(ios(15.0))
{
    decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecisionGrant);
    
}

else if ([message.name isEqualToString:@"cameraAccess"]) {
        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
                if (granted) {
                    NSLog(@“granted”);
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"getCameraAccess()" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                            if (error) {
                                NSLog(@“erorr);
                            } 
                        }];
                    });
                    
                } else {
                    NSLog(@“no granted”);
        }];


- (WKWebView *)wkWebView {
    if (!_wkWebView) {
        WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        wkWebConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
        wkWebConfig.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = YES;
        wkWebConfig.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = YES;
        WKPreferences *preferences = [WKPreferences new];
        preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;
        wkWebConfig.preferences = preferences;
        WKUserContentController *userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc]init];
//        NSString *jSString = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
        NSString *jSString = @"console.log = (function(oriLogFunc){return function(str){oriLogFunc.call(console,str);window.webkit.messageHandlers.log.postMessage(str);}})(console.log);";
        WKUserScript *wkUserScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jSString injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
        [userContentController addUserScript:wkUserScript];
        wkWebConfig.userContentController = userContentController;
        [userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:ZJH5JSLivenessIdTitle];
        [userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:ZJH5JSDismissLoadingTitle];
        [userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:ZJH5JSLivenessResultTitle];
        [userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"cameraAccess"];

        [userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"log"];
        
        _wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, ZJStatusBarHeight, ZJScreenWidth, ZJScreenHeight - ZJStatusBarHeight) configuration:wkWebConfig];
        _wkWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _wkWebView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        _wkWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _wkWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        _wkWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        _wkWebView.UIDelegate = self;
        _wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    }
    return _wkWebView;
}

javascript：
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
          console.log('getUserMedia')
          stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constrains)
          // this.startCompression(stream)
        } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
          console.log('webkitGetUserMedia')
          stream = await navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constrains)
        } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
          console.log('mozGetUserMedia')
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          stream = await navagator.mozGetUserMedia(constrains)
        } else if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
          console.log('old getUserMedia')
          stream = await navigator.getUserMedia(constrains)
        } else {
          console.log('open camera error')
        }

and i also try to use 'navigator.getUserMedia' and 'navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()', this all dont work.
